# TFS 2017 - Is it possible to access the release variable in an environment which was set in another environment in the same release?

Tags: tfs, release-management

In TFS 2017, I set a variable in first environment during the execution using the below command

$myValue= "myValue"

Write-Host ("##vso[task.setvariable variable=myValue;]$myValue")

Is it possible to access this variable in the 2nd environment in the same release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you are using a **environment-level** variable which for values that **vary from environment to environment** (and are the same for all the tasks in an environment).

However, this could be achieved, you just need to use **release definition variables** instead.

> Share values across all of the environments by using **release
>   definition variables.** Choose a release definition variable when you
>   need to use the same value across all the environments and tasks in
>   the release definition, and you want to be able to change the value in
>   a single place. You define and manage these variables in the **Variables**
>   tab in a release definition.

More details about variables in Release Management, please refer this [tutorial](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/concepts/definitions/release/variables).